# Failing at loading offline JSON using Phonegap and wkWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, json, cordova, wkwebview

We have an offline phonegap app that successfully downloads, stored and serves up HTML and linked resources listed in the HTML in an offline concept. Once the "deviceready" event fires our application attempts to load a .JSON file relative as other files in the folder, but fails.

I've tried a few variations on how to load the file, however all fail. I would assume that if a .js file located at /static/js/file.js loads that a similarly referenced JSON file at /static/json/file.json would load through at least one method such as $.getJSON or $.ajax - however none work.

iOS 10.2, xCode 8.2 and using wkWebView instead of the older uiWebView for performance reasons.

Does anyone have a successful current method for loading available offline JSON files?

Comment: Show some code. It looks like you are using JQuery but it's hard to answer without more details.